# Android Studio is not running on ubuntu, no windows pops up even

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I just install android studio through terminal and my ubuntu version is 14.04. I already have java 8 installed on my computer. The procedure I install android studio is exactly the following way:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-studio

But when I finished installing, I click on the Android Studio icon, it just doesn't respond and no windows pops up. I see the icon flickering for a few seconds and then stops. Still, nothing happens. I just wonder why this happens because everything shown by terminal when I install it is perfectly fine. At least I see tons of lines keep appearing through terminal which indicates the installation is processing. Why I can not open and run the Android Studio on my ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can install android-studio with ubuntu-make:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```